# replace simple factory using polymorphism

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, factory-pattern

I am  trying to replace the simple factory **StatsCreatorFactory.java** class  in order to delete the stink multiple use of switch case statements. This is my situation:

**StatsServlet.java**

```
public class StatsServlet extends HttpServlet{ 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        StatsContext context = new StatsContext(request,response);
        **IStatsCreator creator = StatsCreatorFactory.getCreator(context);**
        IChart chart = creator.createChart();
        String jsonChart = creator.chartToJson(chart);
        creator.sendResponse(jsonChart);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

}
```

**IStatsCreator.java**

```
public interface IStatsCreator {

    public IChart createChart() throws IOException;
    public  IDetailsTable createDetailsTable(String itemSelected);

    public String chartToJson(IChart chart);
    public String tableToJson(IDetailsTable table);

    public void sendResponse(String resp) throws IOException;


    public List<File> findFiles() throws IOException, ParseException;
    public List<LogLine> parseFiles(List<File> files) throws IOException;
    public IFileIntervalDateDetector getFileDetector() throws IOException;

    public TargetChartOperation getTargetOperation();
    public IChart getChart();
    public IDetailsTable getDetailsTable();
}
```

**AbstractStatsCreator**

```
public abstract class AbstractStatsCreator implements IStatsCreator{

    protected StatsContext context;

    public AbstractStatsCreator(StatsContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected abstract ILogParser getParser();
    protected abstract IStatsHelper getHelper();

    @Override
    public IFileIntervalDateDetector getFileDetector() throws IOException {
        IFileIntervalDateDetector fileDetector = new FileDetector();
        fileDetector.addPattern(new FileNamePattern(TypeSubjectEnum.valueOf(context.getSubject().toUpperCase()).getFilePattern()));
        fileDetector.addPattern(new FileNamePattern(context.getInstance()));
        return fileDetector;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<File> findFiles() throws IOException, ParseException{
        if(context.getDateStart().equalsIgnoreCase(StringUtils.EMPTY) && context.getDateEnd().equalsIgnoreCase(StringUtils.EMPTY)){
            return getFileDetector().findDailyFiles();
        }

        Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(context.getDateStart());
        Date stopDate = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(context.getDateEnd());
        Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if(DateUtils.isSameDay(startDate, stopDate) && DateUtils.isSameDay(startDate, currentDate)){
            return getFileDetector().findDailyFiles();
        }

        return getFileDetector().findFilesByInterval(context.getDateStart(), context.getDateEnd()); 
    }

    @Override
    public final List<LogLine> parseFiles(List<File> files) throws IOException{
        return getParser().parseLogFiles(files);
    }

    @Override
    public IChart createChart() throws IOException{

        if(context.needUpdate()){
            List<File> files = null;
            try {
                files = findFiles();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                files=Lists.newArrayList();
            }
            List<LogLine> logLines = parseFiles(files);
            context.setLogLines(logLines);
            context.updateContext(); 
        }

        IChart chart = getChart().create();
        return chart;
    }

    @Override
    public IDetailsTable createDetailsTable(String itemSelected) {
        IDetailsTable table = getDetailsTable().create(itemSelected);
        return table;
    }

    @Override
    public String chartToJson(IChart chart) {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(JsonTransformer.renderChart(chart));
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String tableToJson(IDetailsTable table) {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(JsonTransformer.renderDetailsTable(table));
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendResponse(String resp) throws IOException {
        context.getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = context.getResponse().getWriter();
        out.write(resp.toString());
        out.flush();
    }

}
```

**StatsCreatorFactory.java**

```
public class StatsCreatorFactory {

    public static IStatsCreator getCreator(StatsContext context){

        if(context == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context nullo");
        }

        IStatsCreator creator=null;

        switch (context.getOperation()) {
        case "validate":
            creator = new ValidateStatsCreator(context);
            break;
        case "extract":
            creator = new ExtractStatsCreator(context);
            break;
        case "transform":
            creator = new TransformStatsCreator(context);
            break;
        case "view":
            creator = new ViewStatsCreator(context);
            break;  
        default:
            creator = new GeneralStatsCreator(context);
            break;
        }

        return creator;
    }
}
```

I would try to find a way to instantiate ICreator classes avoiding simple factory class, is there any refactoring or design pattern could I use?
Reading Martin Fawler's book I wonder if I can use polymorphism, but I can't find  any way to replicate it in my code.

Comment: You *are* using polymorphism already. This looks clean to me (except for the naming of interfaces with a `I` prefix). You could maybe replace your operation strings by enums, and let each enum instance create the StatsCreator.

Comment: I agree with you and I'll apply these improvements. Actually my code and precisely my Simple factory seem weak and not close for modifications, if I'll add another type of creator, I would modify that method over and over again.

Comment: That's the point of the factory. But the rest of the code will be identical. At some point, if you want some ne feature, you'll need to add changes to the code. As long as it's restricted to the factory (and the new creator class), it's fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first try to modify the IStatsCreator and AbstractStatsCreator to have a stateless bean.

In your example, you have only to get rid of the StatsContext context defined as a class variable in AbstractStatsCreator. So the context should not be bound to the class instance. It should be passed in from outside when ever a method is called on the creator that needs the context. For that you can refactor your IStatsCreator and add the context to all methods that needs it.

for example:

public IChart createChart() throws IOException;

new:

public IChart createChart( StatsContext context ) throws IOException;

and so on.
After that you don't have to create new instances of AbstractStatsCreator implementations for every context call. you just need to have an instance per type. This instances of type can be mapped in the StatsCreatorFactory and just get when they needed. I would also recomend to ged rid of static methods. Make StatsCreatorFactory a real bean that can easier be managed and also easier be mocked for tests.:

```
public class StatsCreatorFactory {

    private Map<String, IStatsCreator> statsCreators = new HashMap<String, IStatsCreator>();

    public void registerStatsCreator( String type, IStatsCreator creator ) {
        statsCreators.put( type, creator );
    }

    public IStatsCreator getCreator( String type ){

        IStatsCreator creator= statsCreators.get( type );

        if(creator == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("no creator registered for type : " + type);
        }

        return creator;
    }
```

}

At the end StatsCreatorFactory is more like a provider then a factory. Maybe you can also rename it to StatsCreatorProvider.

```
public class StatsServlet extneds HttpServlet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private StatsCreatorProvider statsCreatorProvider;

public void init() {
    statsCreatorProvider = new StatsCreatorProvider();
    statsCreatorProvider.registerStatsCreator( "validate", new ValidateStatsCreator() );
    statsCreatorProvider.registerStatsCreator( "extract" new ExtractStatsCreator() );
    ...
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    StatsContext context = new StatsContext(request,response);
    IStatsCreator creator = statsCreatorProvider.getCreator( context.getOperation() );
    IChart chart = creator.createChart( context );
    String jsonChart = creator.chartToJson(chart);
    creator.sendResponse(jsonChart);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

}

Comment: If I understand well with your StatsCreatorProvider in my servlet,  I would have to register before all creators that I suppose to use later and then call methods passing the StatsContext instance. But is't like a client must know all creators API, I want try to encapsulate it, so that the client doesn't need to know what kind of creator is needed.

Comment: Not the client has to know that, only the server must define the creators that it serves and they has to be initialized only once in the initialization of the Servlet (init())

Comment: Ok, maybe my doubt is not strickly correlated to the code I post before, but is more general: **how can you avoid conditional when you need to instantiate a class depending on a parameter type.** maybe is better explain in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866873/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism-nice-in-theory-but-not-practical), I don't see any way to avoid conditional. Can you provide me an example where you can achieve that? Also using the link example if is better for you. Thanks in advance

Comment: "how can you avoid conditional when you need to instantiate a class depending on a parameter type.": yes I only see the possibility to create a (pre-prepared) mapping of paremterType to classType or instance to avoid the switch:case conditions after, just by getting the instance from the mapping. no polymorphism is take in place here so maybe this is not the answer you search for.